# Vue.js application does not run on Gitlab pages

Tags: vue.js, gitlab, vuex

I built a Vue.js Vuex user interface. It works perfectly (on my laptop). I want to deploy it on Gitlab pages.

I used the file described [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/12/vuejs-app-gitlab/) (except that I upgraded the Node.js version):

```
build site:
  image: node:10.8
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

unit test:
  image: node:10.8
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run unit

deploy:
  image: alpine
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache rsync openssh
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - rsync -rav --delete dist/ user@server.com:/your/project/path/
```

The job is marked as run successfully on the pipeline. However when I click on the pages URL I get a 404 HTTP error code.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue when I was trying to deploy my Vue.js application to Gitlab pages. After weeks of trial and error, I have got it to work.

Seeing your above script your building the app, unit testing it and trying to deploy it to an external server. If you need it in Gitlab pages as well you have to use the `pages` job.

Here is my `pages` job for deploying a vue.js app to Gitlab pages:

```
pages:
 image: node:latest
 stage: deploy
 script:
  - npm install --progress=false
  - npm run build
  - rm -rf public
  - mkdir public
  - cp -r dist/* public
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 week
  paths:
  - public
 only:
  - master
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy without the pipeline.  In order for this to work you have to first build your application for production. If you have used Vue cli this is done by invoking the build command. ex. **npm run build**

This will generate a dist folder where your assets are. This is what you have to push in your repository. For example, look at my repository.
https://github.com/DanijelH/danijelh.github.io 
And this is the page 
https://danijelh.github.io/

Comment: Locally your built Index.html page will not work. Once you put it on the server it will.

Comment: I see various JS errors when I deployed the content of **dist/**, so my *index.html* is blank online (on Gitlab)

Comment: That is strange. Please make sure first that your build is successful and that no errors exist while building the application (locally). There is a video that GitLab made to help with the publishing (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWqh9MtT4Bg). Maybe try and follow that example :) Sorry if my comment wasn't helpful, maybe it doesn't work on GitLab but only Github.